# Redirection of page with # to a new page

Tags: 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect `http://www.example.com/#blog` to `http://www.example.com/blog` in WordPress but it doesn't work since the `/#blog` part is considered part of the homepage.

Did you encounter this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

> since the `/#blog` consider as the part of the homepage

Everything after the `#` is called the *fragment identifier*. This part of the URL (ie. `blog` in this case) is not actually sent to the server (the browser strips it from the request), so you can't do this sort of redirect in your server-side logic (ie. regular WordPress redirect).

The fragment identifier can only be manipulated client-side. eg. with JavaScript.

There might be (probably is) a WordPress plugin that will do client-side redirects for you, or you can write some JavaScript code. For example:

```
<script>
if (location.href == 'http://www.example.com/#blog') {
    window.location.replace('http://www.example.com/blog');
}
</script>
```

Note that this is not the same as an HTTP redirect. The client only sees the 200 OK HTTP status, not a 3xx status that is usual (and preferable) with a redirect.

Comment: If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (tick/check on the left) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote answers you find useful (min 15 rep required). Much appreciated, thanks. :)